# How to increase concurrent threading allow count in node-oracledb while connecting to oracle DB?

Tags: node.js, oracle, database-connection, node-oracledb

I am using [node-oracledb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracledb) module for making connection and perform operation with oracle database

There are two approaches to make connection with oracle

1. connection-pool
2. concurrent threads (allows to connect with oracle whenever in need)

I am using second approach where I am creating standalone connection with oracle when in demand

A problem I am facing while making additional connection after successful concurrent 4 connections with oracle. Oracle is not allowing the 5th connection until all created connections become free.

Is there anyway to increase this thread count?

Comment: Use a connection pool.  It has all sort of benefits regarding availability and future scaling.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @ChristopherJones I have already implemented and changes are in production will plan to migrate to pool connection strategy soon.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution how can you increase thread pool size:

start your nodejs app with:

> UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=64 node myapp.js

OR

add the below line in myapp.js (starter file of node js)

> process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=64

Note: 64 is the size of thread pool

More information about Thread Pool

Node worker threads executing   database    statements  on  a   connection  will
commonly    wait    until   round-trips between node-oracledb and   the database
are complete.

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that `process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE` doesn't have any effect on Windows - you must set the environment variable before starting Node.js on that operating system.  The node-oracledb [Connections, Threads, and Parallelism](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#numberofthreads) documentation discusses this.

Comment: @ChristopherJones thanks for your suggestion, but I am gonna to use linux machine for deployment so I think if will work fine there